How to use Flask-SocketIO with Phusion Passenger?
Phusion Passenger needs to launch the webserver using its own function, so a custom function to launch a webserver cannot be used, while SocketIO seems to require to use one. Is there is any way to bypass this?
Sample code:
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask('')
socket = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return open("index.html", "r").read()

@socket.on('echo')
def echo(json):
    return json

# Phusion Passenger already does this, so we shouldnt run that next line or else we will never run the program
#app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80)

